# What kind of math is required to solve packing problems?

Tags: optimization, packing-problem

Sometimes while I'm daydreaming I come up with math problems for myself, to solve.  I don't know why but they are mostly packing problems.  I don't know how to solve them mathematically but I could probably use a genetic algorithm to find solutions.

But there are ways to prove packing solutions.  How is this done?  What branch of math would you classify this as?

Comment: Somewhere in the intersection of Computational Geometry and Optimization.

Comment: A dose of combinatorics wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Packing problems are often notoriously difficult. I know one professor who likes to assign unsuspecting high school students an unsolved, seemingly simple packing problem.